# How can I access my external hard drive wirelessly from my laptop?

Tags: wireless-networking, laptop, external-hard-drive

My desktop crashed so I am migrated over to a laptop.  I have wireless in my home so I am trying to be able to use to laptop in any room without any other connections (wireless printer, wireless mouse, etc)

The one issue I have is that my desktop had 2 external hard drives (USB) connected to them and I am trying to figure out the best way to treat these as external drives without having to plug them into the laptop directly.

My external hard drive is [the Western Digital WDH1U5000N 500GB](http://news.compusa.com/western-digital-wdh1u5000n-500gb-35-external-hard-drive/836/) and my laptop is [a Dell D620.](http://www.notebookreview.com/default.asp?newsID=2846)

Comment: I know this might sound dumb. But wouldn't it be easier just to have a laptop docking station ?

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to use a NAS (Network Attached Storage) adapter to connect your USB drives to your router. This would make them part of your network, so that you can get to them from any device connected to the network (wired or wireless). Here is an example of a NAS adapter:

http://www.addonics.com/products/nasu2.php

Answer (score 0):

You could always purchase a hard drive case that has a built in wireless connection, then move the external hard drive to it.

Answer (score 0):

You might check your router as well. I have a d-link 625 and it has a USB port that can be programed for network adapter. It required a firmware update from d-link and selecting this option from the d-link web based console, downloading 'share port' and now I have a usb printer and hard drive accessible by everyone on my network.

If your router has a USB port in back, do some research from the vendor as many now support that port for more uses than network setup.

Note: I attached a four port USB hub to the port on the router so it can pick up four items that get plugged into it.